# Jquery Dialog Box does not stay open within form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Does anybody know why if I try to place the button to open a dialog box (jquery dialog widget) within a form it pops open for a split second and then closes? Outside it works just fine.

So if I put:

```
<form>
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
</form>
```

It appears to be submitting form, although form has its own submit button?

```
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening? I seem to be too thick to grasp why opening from a button within a form element would cause it to not work? :)

PS: I also tried putting the div outside the form but that makes no difference. If the button is inside the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the button tag you are using. Every time you click the button the form get submited because the button is inside the scope of form. One way is to change the button tag into input type button or try like this using pure js:

html:

```
<form>
<button id="opener" onclick="return showPopup()">open the dialog</button>
</form>
```

js:

```
function showPopup(){
//code to show your dialog
return false
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it WORKED :) ... If you could you please explain why the purpose of the return in the onclick that would be fantastic? Thanks again.

Comment: When you click the button(only the button tag not input type button) inside a form, the form get submitted. But before submitting the form if there is some js code specified on the click event of the button, first the js get executed and the form get submitted. This is happened in your case. We can stop the execution inside the javascript by returning false to the calling event or proceed upon certain conditions by returning true like demonstrated above.

Answer (score 2):

Try to return a false from click handler after opening the dialog as below:

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
   return false;
});
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is because a buttons default type is `submit`, so clicking it will always submit the form and reload the page.

Change the buttons type, and it will not submit the form:

```
<form>
   <button id="opener" type="button">open the dialog</button>
</form>
```